# jscript pop up error when executing selenium-side runner code-800A03F6

Tags: jscript, selenium-side-runner

I am trying to execute selenium script on grid using npm in visual studio:
selenium-side-runner *.side -w 10 --server http://localhost:4444/wd/hub

But I am getting the pop up error saying "Microsoft jscript compilation error" with code: 800A03F6.

```
  C:\Users\Ashok Kumar>npm -v
        6.14.12
    {
        "name": "selenium-runner",
            "version": "1.0.0",
           "main": "index.js",
       "scripts": {
         "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
         },
            "author": "",
            "license": "ISC",
             "devDependencies": {
         "selenium-side-runner": "^4.0.0-alpha.46"
        },
        "dependencies": {},
         "description": ""
         }
```